# Deploy handlebar .hbs files to AWS Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, handlebars.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I use handlebars templates with javascript to build out my views on the frontend. Using the AWS publish tool in Visual Studio 2015, when deploying to an environment it does not pass over my handlebar template files (.hbs files) but it has not problem with the html files.

They are in my VS project but when I deploy they do not show up in the deployed application folders, is there some setting that I need to change in the deployment that will allow these files to be deployed?

Here is my VS folder:

[image: VS Image]

And this is what shows up after deploying:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be an issue with the AWS deployment tool. When adding some of the HBS files the build action was defaulted to "None". We had to change it to "Content"
[image]